# Cannot see tables from my database in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-sqlite, show

I did some research about showing the tables from my application database. all tutorials stated that this command "slite> .tables" will show them, but the response I always get is ".tables". I am using Android 2.2 virtual device. I can see my database: # sqlite3 data/data/my_package/databases/X.db. After this command I get:

> SQLite version 3.6.22
>   Enter “.help” for instructions
>   Enter SQL statements terminated with a “;”
>   sqlite> .tables

The response is  ".tables", instead of tables from the database. I know I am creating those tables,because in the application I can see that information.
I must be doing something wrong, just don't see what. Did someone got this error too and found a reasonable explanation?

Comment: I would think you would need to run some SQL to describe the tables from the database

Comment: Simply using '.tables' works for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be an equivalent statement:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: hmm. this is weird. if i run the command above i get this response: "SELECT: not found", if i run the command like this "# sqlite3 select name from sqlite_master where type='table' order by name;" i get this result "sqlite3 select name from sqlite_master where type='table' order by name;
sqlite3: Error: too many options: "from"
Use -help for a list of options."

Comment: After you call `sqlite3 data/data/my_package/databases/X.db` from a command prompt,  try `CREATE TABLE tmp (temp text);` at the sqlite prompt.  Does it return you to the sqlite prompt without error, or does it tell you that it can't open the database?  If the latter, the path to your database is wrong.  If the former, try the first select statement I gave you from the sqlite prompt; does tmp show up?

Comment: i run the create table tmp command and i got "create: not found". wondering why the path to the db is not correct. if i want to see all the packages, # ls data/data/ i can see my project there, and # ls data/data/package../databases i get the name of the database. and right after that command i am trying the creation of tmp table or the select sql from above.

Comment: What sort of computer are you on?

Comment: windows vista premium. it's like i have to activate something to make the command prompt interpret my sql commands. can't understand why i get no reaction from it besides the above of course.

Comment: Are you sure you're typing the sql commands at the sqlite command prompt and not at the windows command prompt?  If you're using Eclipse, trying using DDMS to grab a copy of your database out from the emulator and put it in the same directory as your sqlite3.exe and try it without the path reference.  Otherwise, I've got no clue, sorry; it works for me on both XP and Windows7.

Comment: finally it worked. i had to adb pull data/data.... and it creates me a new file .db in the android sdk folder and that i can open with sqlbrowser. thank you.